# aapt tool - throws error

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-tools

When I try to use the aapt tool in command prompt, I am getting the error as I have mentioned in the below snapshot. Kindly let me know if I need to do some setup to run this tool

```
$ aapt dump badging C:\Users\pcuser\Desktop\KidsAPP\fun.apk
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure there is appt.exe in C:\Android\platform-tools,

Then try this code:

```
aapt dump badging C:\Users\pcuser\Desktop\KidsAPP\fun.apk
```

there is no $ in the command.

You also can enter into C:\Android\platform-tools by

```
 cd /d C:\Android\platform-tools
```

to execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have aapt in your platform tools folder,
try to get the tools in following two links:

https://android-apktool.googlecode.com/files/apktool-install-windows-r05-ibot.tar.bz2

https://android-apktool.googlecode.com/files/apktool1.5.2.tar.bz2

just put all the files in same folder to run.

The aapt project page:
https://android-apktool.googlecode.com/

Answer (score 0):

set your android sdk path upto platform-tools in command line e.g if it exit in D:\android-sdks\platform-tools then set that path in command line and then run this command aapt dump badging C:\Users\pcuser\Desktop\KidsAPP\fun.apk